# print unicode characters in python interpreter

Tags: python, unicode

I am playing around working with `unicode` in python.
I am not able to `print (display)` the `unicode characters` such as`é`
I tried the following:

```
>>> sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF8')
>>> chr(0xFF)
'\xff'
>>> u = u'abcdé'
>>> len(u)
5
>>> u[4]  
u'\xe9'
>>> str(u[4])
'\xc3\xa9'
>>>
```

I was expecting `u[4]` to print `é` but it prints `u'\xe9'`. how can I make this work?
I am using `python 2.7.2 version`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you just type `u[4]`, it shows the repr. To see the unicode character, use print.

```
print u[4]
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked, so setting `sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF8')` is not needed I guess?

Comment: @eagertoLearn: No, don't use `setdefaultencoding()`; that is *very rarely* a good idea.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks, I will not use it. but may I know why is it a bad idea? and whats it purpose then?

Comment: @eagertoLearn: It's an internal method used by Python to set the default encoding from the environment, to match your terminal settings. Mostly, people setting it don't understand how automatic encoding and decoding works for Unicode values, and should instead investigate how to avoid the automatic conversions.